# Exclude categories from search query

Tags: categories, wp-query, search

I have two categories that I want to exclude from my search results, so far without luck.

I have tried adding the following piece of code but it didn't work.

```
$search_query = query_posts(array('category__in' => array(-22, -21)));
```

Here is my current code.

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$searchq = new WP_Query($search_query);

while ($searchq->have_posts()) : $searchq->the_post();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pre_get_posts action to exclude categories from search query.

```
function wcs_exclude_category_search( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

  if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-22, -21' );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wcs_exclude_category_search', 1 );
```

You should paste this code in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried similar solutions that I found on the internet but none seem to work. I'm starting to think maybe it's a problem with my search form. Will report back if I find out anything.

Comment: I ended up fixing my issues by removing "$query->" from "$query->is_search". I did this because the unwanted categories would still show up if you entered an empty search query.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's the objective of `if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )` ?

Comment: Ok great, and how would this work with categories from custom post types? Thanks!

Comment: @Yuri don't post replies as new solutions, and post new questions as new questions not comments https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask