# Is there a way to 'archive' inactive categories?

Tags: categories

Is there a way (using a plugin or otherwise) to 'archive' categories in WordPress which were previously used for the structure of a website, but are not presently used?

I want to clean up the categories section in the backend of my website to make it easier for users to see the parent categories only which are of the most importance.

I don't want to delete all of the old and child categories, in case these are used again in the future.

Comment: So your actual question is how to only show categories that have posts in them in the category list on the edit screen? Have you considered deleting them? As far as the question taken literally, no there's no archive status unless you build one from scratch, terms don't have statuses like posts do

Comment: No, there's a load of categories that have 1,000+ posts which are no longer going to be used going forward. However if there's a chance that the category might be reinstated, that's why I don't want to just delete the category.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162232/exclude-categories-from-search-query)

You can just remove category from search results.

Comment: I want to remove categories from the backend: [Like in this example, I only want to keep 'WTCC' category...](https://www.touringcars.net/Categories.png) and 'archive' all of the child categories, to tidy up the edit screen. There's a chance I might wish for the child categories to be reinstated in the future without losing their attributed posts.

Comment: Try to archive them using costum post type.